# How to only show public posts and not show private ones in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection (or post if you prefer) that a User creates. The collection can be public or private (default is true in database). I want to let the User see all of their collections, but want anyone to be able to see ONLY collections set to be public.

What I mean is that when anyone (User or not) goes to view the Collection (ex. myapp.com/collections/some-collection), if it is public it will show, but it it is private it will not show and maybe render a "This Collection is Private" and redirect. I could use some help, thanks!

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "collections", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.boolean  "display",     default: true
  t.text     "description"
end
```

**app/views/collections/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <h2><%= best_in_place @collection, :title, as: :input %></h2>
    <p><%= best_in_place @collection, :description, as: :textarea %></p>
    <%= simple_form_for @collection do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :display, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/controllers/collections_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @links = @collection.follows
  @collection = Collection.find_by_id(params[:id]) if params[:id].present?
  if params[:id].blank?
    @collections = Collection.user_collections(params.merge({"user_id" => current_user.id}))
  end   
end
```

**app/models/collection.rb**

```
  class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :follows

      def links_count
          follows.count
      end

      def add_link(url)
          status, options, link = Link.link_exist?(url)
          unless status
              options = Utils.parse_page(url)
              link = Link.create(options)
              link.download_image!
          end
          link.follow_link({:collection_id => self.id, :user_id => user_id})
      end

      def self.user_collections(options)
          conds = []
          conds << " user_id = #{options["user_id"]}" if options["user_id"].present?
          conds = conds.blank? ? [] : conds.join(" AND ")
          Collection.where(conds).order("updated_at DESC").page(options["page"]).per(16)
      end
  end
```

Comment: please paste your collection.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
before_filter :is_public?, only: [ :action_name]

def is_public?
  unless @collection.display?
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Comment: To be more specific, I mean that when anyone goes to view the Collection (ex. myapp.com/collections/some-collection), if it is public it will show, but it it is private it will not and maybe render a "This Collection is Private" and redirect.

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked! Got an error with the redirect back, but will change it to redirect to User instead. Also got some undefined method error, so I removed it just for testing and it was all good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@collections = Collection.where('display', true)` This should return all collections that can be displayed.